# Merge values of one database field into another database field

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I use cart66, and it saves the product variations in **option_1**
However, we entered all our product variations in  **option_2**

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IIti.png)

Is there a command to run that would copy all the values of option_2  into option_1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE yourtable SET option_1 = option_2
```

Comment: Thanks that worked great. If you dont mind, can you give me the command to now  clear the option_2 table?  Because i don't need both to be duplicates.